# Responsive web design and resizing images

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Repsonsive web design works great on most html elements excepts images.I find it a mess. When resizing viewports, you cannot use resizing percentages on an image since it will take on the parent element width and height right. You need to set fixed widths and heights for images...Or am I missing something?

So how exactly do you do a responsive design involving images whose container element/parent will stretch above its native width and shrink below its native width?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The done thing in responsive design is to set this in your css for images and some other elements:

```
img, embed, object, video {
max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Then in your html the image simply takes up the size of it's container.

You do not set the image size itself you just let it grow/shrink itself.

Comment: what about the height? does it auto-size with the width? Also, what about IE6-7, does it support max-width?

Comment: The height will scale automatically. Here's some more info on images including how to make them work in older versions of IE if you want/have to support them: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

Answer (score 2):

well - you can write:  .selector img{width: 100%; height: auto;}  and then use the size of the  div it is in to determine it's scale.  or you can also set the image as a background and use similar methods and maybe even mess around with background-size: cover.  i'll make a jsfiddle...

```
.image-w img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done on my site is this:

page stuff....

```
div class=picr>

img src="/Images/Home/MountainPine.jpg" alt="Mountain Pine" id="mountainpine" >

<p>Caption about mountain pine</p>

/div>
```

Then in CSS

```
pic, pic6 {
    float: left;
    }

...

.pic, .picr {
    width: 37%;
    }

#content  img {
    width: 100% ;
    }
```

So the div class is styled, and the picture is set to fill it.  By using the div, then I can also style

within the .pic classes to be distinctive from the body text.